# Java, Selenium webdriver TestNG "Pls Help Me"

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I have a scenario a single sign on page before a user can get a full access to the secure site, they have to request for a one-time password using the request button on the page, 
the one password is then sent to their inbox.

First screen user enters username and password and click login
then gets to the second screen which they have to request for the one-time password

The script will have to sleep and get.url to email, get the password from email and back to the single sign on page and paste, click on the submit button and secure page is now displayed.

How do I go about writing this script?

I have a pageobject called LoginPage and Testcase called LoginTest

Answer (score 1):

You will need to automate an email.  This will mean that you should use a service that connects to email via IMAP or POP (If you don't know what services, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629246/recommended-java-api-for-receiving-e-mails-pop3-and-imap)).

The process will look something like this:

1. Login, and have email sent
2. Connect to email via IMAP/POP3
3. Get the text of the email (you may have to do parse afterwards)
4. Type in the code

Comment: I'd add that it is best to take the "gmail/outlook" bit outside of Selenium -> as in, don't attempt to automate anything on their sites. It's quicker and more reliable if you can get a library to do that for you.

Comment: I've never used anything like that...do you have suggestions?

Comment: Realistically, any library that allows you to connect to a mailbox using IMAP or POP3 can be used. However specifically I know of [JavaMail](https://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/) and for C#, [IMapX](http://imapx.codeplex.com/) ...also worth thinking about if your application stores the emails elsewhere too. For instance, ours stores a copy of the email to the database and *then* sends it off to the user. We save a bunch of time by just querying the database to get the email, rather than connecting to Gmail *at all* (but it isn't a "true" representation, I suppose).

Comment: I like that solution, but without knowing how the application works, its pretty impossible to suggest it.  Updating.